# CoverFlow app for Screenshots

Tags: kde, qt, screenshot, kde-apps

Does anyone remember how the tiny little KDE/QT tool to create stylish (reminiscent of iTunes' CoverFlow effect) screenshots with reflections? One could select some screenshots (or other pictures) and configure how big the reflection should be, in what proportions the pictures are etc.

I remember it was once mentioned in one of the blogs in planetkde.org.

There is a QT plugin called PictureFlow, but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Screenie ?**

https://code.google.com/p/screenie/

> Screenie a small tool to allow you to compose a fancy and stylish
>   screenshots. It is cross-platform (for Linux, Windows and Mac OS X)
>   and very easy to use. You will have an impressive screenshot in just
>   one minute!

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=screenie&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

[image]

Comment: yes, thanks :) human memory is still better than google!